# Cut -f parameter not working correctly

Tags: bash, shell, cut

I use next command

```
out=cat /path/myFile | cut -f2,3 -d ',' | sed -r -e 's/,/ /g
```

myFile looks like:

```
a1a1a1a1,b1b1b1b1,c1c1c1c1,d1d1d1d1d1
a2a2a2a2,b2b2b2b2,c2c2c2c2,d2d2d2d2d2
a3a3a3a3,b3b3b3b3,c3c3c3c3,d3d3d3d3d3
```

and after i would got :

```
b1b1b1b1 c1c1c1c1
b2b2b2b2 c2c2c2c2
```

but result is write at one line:

```
b1b1b1b1 c1c1c1c1 b2b2b2b2 c2c2c2c2 ...
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: There are syntax errors in your code but they are apparently just transcription errors. Prefer `$(cmd)` over ` `cmd\` `. The [`cat` is useless](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html). The `sed` would be more efficient to replace with `tr , ' '`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are saying `echo $out` without quotes instead if the correct

```
echo "$out"
```

Answer (score 1):

You had a quote problem :

```
out="$(cat /tmp/myfile | cut -f2,3 -d ',' | sed -r -e 's/,/ /g';)"
```

works and $out have :

```
b1b1b1b1 c1c1c1c1
b2b2b2b2 c2c2c2c2
b3b3b3b3 c3c3c3c3
```

Also, for single character replacement, you could use `tr`

```
out="$(cat /tmp/myfile | cut -f2,3 -d ',' | tr ',' ' ')"
```

Then, to use it :

```
echo "$out"
```